# Using interp1 in R

Tags: r

I am using `interp1` from the 'pracma' package (v 2.0.7) in R version 3.3.3 on Windows 10 x64.

I want NA's returned when `xi` is outside the range of `x`. This is a basic question, but I've tried looking online and can't find exactly what I am looking for.

`interp1` use to have this feature (`'extrap'`)? [Doc for version 0.7](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/signal/versions/0.7-6/topics/interp1).

```
#library(pracma)
x  = c(2,4,5,6,8,9)
y  = c(0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7,0.3,0.2)
xi = c(1,2,4,6,8)
yi = interp1(x,y,xi,method = "linear")

# my error message:
Error in interp1(x, y, xi, method = "linear") : 
  Points 'xi' outside of range of argument 'x'.
```

Instead of an error, how can I retrieve `yi` so that it just says NA on the end where `xi` is outside the range of `x`?

For instance, when I do this same code in MatLab, with it's `interp1` function. I get an extrapolation.

```
yi = interp1(x,y,xi,'linear','extrap')
yi = 0.2  0.3  0.5  0.7  0.3
```

And when I remove the `'extrap'` clause, I get an NaN:

```
yi = NaN  0.3  0.5  0.7  0.3
```

Is there a way to achieve the equivalent in R without rewriting the `interp1` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `?interp1` will tell you (emphasis mine):

> xi: Numeric vector; points at which to compute the interpolation;
>             **all points must lie between ‘min(x)’ and ‘max(x)’**.

So you will have to code something for yourself, if `xi` lies outside that range.

Here is an example, where I define a short new function `interp2` that gives `NA`'s for `xi` values outside of `range(x)`.

```
# Your sample data
x <- c(2,4,5,6,8,9);
y <- c(0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7,0.3,0.2);
xi <- c(1,2,4,6,8);

# New function interp2
interp2 <- function(x, y, xi = x, ...) {
    yi <- rep(NA, length(xi));
    sel <- which(xi >= range(x)[1] & xi <= range(x)[2]);
    yi[sel] <- interp1(x = x, y = y, xi = xi[sel], ...);
    return(yi);
}

yi <- interp2(x, y, xi, method = "linear");
#[1]  NA 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.3
```

---

## A more general comment

If you take a look at the sample data, any interpolation results are probably to be taken with a *large* grain of salt. More generally, a more robust approach would be to fit a linear model, which you can then use to get predictions for *any* new values `x` (including uncertainties)

```
ynew <- predict(lm(y ~ x), data.frame(x = xi));
#    1     2     3     4     5
#0.484 0.466 0.430 0.394 0.358
```

For your sample data, the linear fit is obviously not very good.

Alternatively, you can also get predictions based on a local polynomial regression fit (LOESS). This will give you similar results to `pracma::interp1` (ignoring the warnings which stem from too few data points).

```
ynew <- predict(loess(y ~ x), data.frame(x = xi));
#  1   2   3   4   5
# NA 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful. A LOESS might be the best way forward instead of modifying interp2. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries @SydS112688 . Glad to help.